# FMX.Graphics.TCanvas.DrawEllipse doesn't work on Android

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, rad-studio

I'm making simple drawing application with FireMonkey and Delphi. All it really does is drawing lines and ellipses. This is the code:

```
Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
with Form1 do begin
for i := 0 to 360 do
  if (i mod 15)=0 then
  begin
    p1 := TPointF.Create(PX, PY);
    p2 := TPointF.Create(Round(PX+200*sin(i*pi/180)), Round(PY+200*cos(i*pi/180)));
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawLine(p1, p2, 100);
  end;

for i := 0 to 200 do
  if (i mod 20)=0 then
  begin
    prst1 := TRectF.Create(PX+i,PY+i,PX-i,PY-i);
    Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawEllipse(prst1, 100);
  end;
 Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
```

This code works perfectly when I compile it under Win32 or Win64. But when I try to compile it and run on an Android device, only lines show up, and ellipses are just missing. Does anyone have an idea why is that happening?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Drawing inside an image control isn't really the proper way to draw on the screen. Try drawing directly onto the form canvas from within the form's `OnPaint` event handler.

Comment: Please always provide details like variable initialization and types. E.g. What value do `PX` and `PY` have at entry? What if they happen to be 123456? What is the context of the code? Event handler? Your defined method? What are the `brush` and `stroke` propertiy values? Bonus question: What is the opacity value for a fully opaque line?

Comment: @TomBrunberg Sorry for that. Both `PX` and `PY` are 200, and `TImage` is 400x400 so they really just represent the centre of the `TImage`. The code is under `ButtonClick` procedure - I just want to draw radar-like surface on the image. Then I'm drawing trajectories on it. I just have `stroke` and `color` property values, they are `3` for `stroke` and `TAlphaColors.Black` for `color`. Opacity value in Object Inspector for `TImage` is `1` (if this is what you are asking about).

Comment: I'm just having problem with understanding why the same FireMonkey code works under Win32 but doesn't work under Android. I'm pretty new to Delphi and I believed that the same code will work identically under both of them. Embarcadero wiki isn't really that helpful for me with my limited knowledge.

Will using TPaintBox will be better than TImage in my situation when I want to draw multiple trajectories on it (so editing it in loop that works for about 1000steps)?

Comment: Thanks for responding to my comment, but please add that info to your question, here in the comments it is so easily overlooked. My q regarding opacity stems from your line: `Image1.Bitmap.Canvas.DrawLine(p1, p2, 100);`. The third parameter is the opacity, 0..1.0 acc docs, but ok, anything above 1.0 is considered 1.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw on the `Form.Canvas` in the `OnPaint` event handler. Here is an example:

```
procedure TForm1.FormPaint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
begin
  with Canvas do begin
    BeginUpdate;
    try
      Stroke.Kind := TBrushKind.Solid;
      Stroke.Thickness := 2.0;
      DrawEllipse(ARect,1);
      DrawLine(PointF(ARect.Left,ARect.Height / 2), PointF(ARect.right,ARect.Height / 2), 1);
      DrawLine(PointF(ARect.Left+(ARect.Width / 2),ARect.Height), PointF(ARect.Left+(ARect.Width / 2),0), 1);
    finally
      EndUpdate;
    end;
  end;
end;
```